# Trying to return the name from Artist class, not sure where I'm going wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an array of artists and I want to eventually pick a random artist from the bunch. But I can't get it to display the artist's name.

```
const artistDiv = document.querySelector(".random-artist");

let artists = [];

function Artist(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const test = "test";

function addArtists() {
    artists.push(new Artist(test));
}

let x = Math.random() * (artists.length - 1);
let randomArtist = artists[x].name;

artistDiv.innerHTML = randomArtist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `addArtists()` function and hence nothing gets added to the `artists` array. Hence, You must also be getting error like this - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`.

So, call that function and try.

```js
let artists = [];

function Artist(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const test = "test";

// You forgot to call this function to add into artists array
function addArtists(test) {
  artists.push(new Artist(test));
}

// Adding any 3 random names into array for demo purpose
addArtists(test);
addArtists("Artist 1");
addArtists("Random dude");
addArtists("JS artist");

// Note that you must use Math.round() here to get a integer value
// Otherwise you will get a float value which won't give correct result
let x = Math.round(Math.random() * (artists.length - 1));

// Finally indexing by random index x and console logging it
let randomArtist = artists[x].name;
console.log(randomArtist)

document.querySelector('.randomArtist').innerHTML = randomArtist;
```

```html
<div class="randomArtist"></div>
```

Comment: I can't believe i forgot to actually call the function to add the artists lol

Comment: @jrob11 Yea, that was a mistake. Another correction I made was by including `Math.round()`. Now, the code will return a random artist from array successfully . Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This line :

`let x = Math.random() * (artists.length - 1);`

won't give you an integer, but a float.

ex:

`Math.random() * 5 = 3.4956451806577418`

Then accessing the array with a float is likely to return null. (the float being converted to string, and you'r trying to access a hashmap)

use 'round' math function to get an integer

`let x =Math.round(Math.random() * (artists.length - 1));`

You might need to add 1 to be sure to access all the values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention, that I tried `artists[0].name` and it won't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the function `addArtists`.

Just do this `addArtists()` after declaring it.

Otherwise, you are using the values of an empty array.

Try like this:

```js
const artistDiv = document.querySelector(".random-artist");

let artists = [];

function Artist(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const test = "test";

function addArtists() {
    artists.push(new Artist(test));
}
addArtists();
let x = Math.random() * (artists.length - 1);

let randomArtist = artists[x].name;

artistDiv.innerHTML = randomArtist;
```

```html
<div class="random-artist"></div>
```